# Installer not launching .NetFramework

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, setup-project

I am using Setup project to install my application.I have added .NetFramework 3.5 SP1 and Windows Installer 3.1 in Prerequisites and selected "Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application".

But when I tried to install Installer goes to Microsoft website to download .NetFramework.
why it is not installing from my machines local copy?
what am missing here?

Comment: are you using ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the full .NET 3.5 SP1 install (around 237mb) or the 2.8mb bootstrapper. If you are using the latter then this is the nature of a bootstrapper. It checks what is missing and then goes to Microsoft to download what is needed.

See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986 for the full install package.